# Python: what is the correct way to raise an alarm if value isn't what expected?

Tags: python

I have a list of files whos name contains some data i am collecting.

I want to

1. check that the data is correct,
2. if not raise an allarm

What is the correct way of doing this?
My code works, but am not sure if i should be raising a NameError, or another type

```py
expected_value='has-to-be-this-exact-value'

#importing files, with information stored in the name
filename_1 = 'whatever_has-to-be-this-exact-value'
filename_2 = 'whatever_not-the-same-should-raise-error'

def catch_name_error (filename, expected_value):
    if filename.split('_')[1]!=expected_value:
        print (filename.split('_')[1])
        raise NameError("Names dont match")

catch_name_error(filename_1,expected_value)  
print ('nothing happend')
catch_name_error(filename_2, expected_value)
```

out:

```py
nothing happend
not-the-same-should-raise-error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-d6f6ad995399> in <module>
     12 catch_name_error(filename_1,expected_value)
     13 print ('nothing happend')
---> 14 catch_name_error(filename_2, expected_value)

<ipython-input-62-d6f6ad995399> in catch_name_error(filename, expected_value)
      8     if filename.split('_')[1]!=expected_value:
      9         print (filename.split('_')[1])
---> 10         raise NameError("Names dont match")
     11 
     12 catch_name_error(filename_1,expected_value)

NameError: Names dont match
```

Comment: I suggest raising a `ValueError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the list of built-in exceptions in the Python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

In your case, it seems like a [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) might be suitable:

> *exception* `ValueError`
>
> Raised when an operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as `IndexError`.

Comment: thanks, and is it more common to put the "raise error" sequence into its own function and call it when you need it;  or should i write it into every funciton outright?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "try-except with ValueError"

```
def catch_name_error (filename, expected_value):
    try:
        if filename.split('_')[1]!=expected_value:
            print (filename.split('_')[1])
    except ValueError:
            print("The name has error or something ")
```